# Problems while returning RSSI value of a Bluetooth device

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am developing an Android application using Eclipse to return the RSSI values of a Bluetooth device. I have modified the Android Bluetooth Chat example to fit my needs, but I am having problems returning the RSSI value. After hitting the <kbd>Scan</kbd> button to discover nearby devices it returns the device name, device address, and is also suppose to return the RSSI value but instead it says `null` for the RSSI.

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        // When discovery finds a device
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
           // Get the Bluetooth RSSI
            short Rssi = intent.getShortExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_RSSI,Short.MIN_VALUE);
            // If it's already paired, skip it, because it's been listed already
            // Added getRssi()
            if (device.getBondState() != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress() + getRssi());
            }
        // When discovery is finished, change the Activity title
        } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
            setTitle(R.string.select_device);
            if (mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.getCount() == 0) {
                String noDevices = getResources().getText(R.string.none_found).toString();
                mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(noDevices);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is very late but, On this line,
`mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress() + getRssi());`
You shouldn't be saying `getRssi();`
It should be your variable `Rssi`.
That's how I get my RSSI value anyway..